# Showing a property with regards to a vector tangent to a point on the hyperboloid!

Tags: calculus, vectors

Considering the positive half of the standard hyperboloid $$S^+ = \{(x,y,z) : -x^2 - y^2 + z^2 = 1, z > 0\},$$ any point $(x,y,y) \in S^+,$ and the vector $<a,b,c>$ tangent to that point $(x,y,z),$ I must show that $-ax - by + cz = 0.$ Then, I must use this fact to show that $a^2 + b^2 - c^2 > 0.$

I have been having a lot of difficulty. I am not very comfortable with vectors.

(1) I have recognized that $-ax - by + cz = 0$ implies that the vectors $<-a,-b,c>$ and $<x,y,z>$ are perpendicular. However, I do not know how to leverage the fact that $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ is tangent to the point $(x,y,z)$ in order to show that $\langle -a,-b,c \rangle,$ or $\langle a,b,-c \rangle.$ Is perpendicular to the vector $\rangle x,y,z \rangle.$ The angle between $\langle a,b,-c \rangle$ and $\langle a,b,c \rangle,$ as well as the angle between $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ and $ \langle x,y,z\rangle $ varies according to the values of $x,y,z,a,b,c.$

May I have some guidance or some direction? Maybe a hint as to how to employ the fact that $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ is tangent to $(x,y,z).$

(2) Moreover, That $a^2 + b^2 - c^2 > 0$ implies that the angles between $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ and $\langle a,b,-c \rangle$ is between $0$ and $90$ degrees, right? Is there anything that suggests that angle between the two vectors is so?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: FYI, use `\langle` and `\rangle` to get $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ instead of $<a,b,c>$.

Comment: alright, thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) A tangent vector must be the velocity vector of some path $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ on the hyperboloid. That is, we get the vector $(x'(0),y'(0),z'(0))=(a,b,c)$. If we write out the equation

$$ -x(t)^2-y(t)^2+z(t)^2=1, $$

implicitly differentiate both sides and plug in $t=0$, what do we get?

(2) The hyperboloid is asymptotic to the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$. A vector on the top half of the cone, and a vector on the bottom half with the same $x,y$ coordinates (and opposite $z$ coordinate) are exactly a right angle apart from each other. Tangent vectors to the hyperboloid are on the other side of this cone (pointing more horizontally than vertically) so $(a,b,c)$ and $(a,b,-c)$ are $<90^{\circ}$ apart.

---

Here is a way to show $-a^2-b^2+c^2<0$. Assume $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$ are nonzero.

Define the "pseudo-Euclidean" dot product $(x,y,z)\cdot(a,b,c)=-ax-by+cz$.

The hyperboloid is then "pseudosphere" $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}=1$. Define the quadratic function

$$ f(t)= (\vec{x}+t\vec{v})\cdot(\vec{x}+t\vec{v})=\vec{x}\cdot \vec{x}+2t(\vec{x}\cdot \vec{v})+t^2(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v})=\vec{x}\cdot \vec{x}+t^2(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}) $$

where $\vec{v}=(a,b,c)$. The third components $z$ and $c$ are both nonzero, so there exists a $t$ for which the third component of $\vec{x}+t\vec{v}$ is zero, in which case $f(t)\le 0$, impossible unless $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}<0$.

Comment: Hey, runway! Thank you for the response. Plugging in $t = 0$ gives values for $x'(t), y'(t), z'(t).$ We arrive at $(x(0), y(0), z(0) = (x,y,z)$ via a convenient parametrization, or how? Also, would you say that explaining why $(a, b, c)$ and $(a, b, -c)$ are $< 90$ degrees apart is the best approach for that part? Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, $(x(0),y(0),z(0))=(x,y,z)$. When you differentiated the equation and plugged in $t=0$ you got the equation you wanted, right? | When you say "the best approach for that part," what does "that part" refer to?

Comment: Yes! But, why is it that $x(0),y(0),z(0) = x,y,z,$ respectively? I meant for part (2)!

Comment: I don't understand what you want in part (2). Did you just want an explanation why a tangent vector to the hyperboloid and its reflection across the $xy$-plane were within a right angle of each other? Or are you being asked for a proof in some exercise? You have not made it clear. I assumed you already knew they were within a right angle and were asking for an explanation. As for a proof, use the fact that $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}=\|x\|\|y\|\cos\theta$.

Comment: Hey. Well, I am trying to prove that $a^2 + b^2 - c^2 > 0.$ If I could show that $(a, b, c)$ and $(a, b, -c)$ are less than $90$ degrees form each other, then that would essentially prove the statement. But, I wasn't sure if that is the "best" (as in concise, straightforward) way to prove that statement.

Comment: @Ana I edited with a proof.